# Data synch issue in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

We use a oracle 11g database, and we have data coming from our app as well as from external resources.

Now we have some tables that are populated from both UI and the external process/sources, and we have a mapping table in between **(this is the important part).**

Since the data from the external sources loads once a day (while the app users are inactive), we have a stored procedure(`stored_procedure_x`) in place that synchs the records(by inserting data in the mapping table) and it works fine. We are able to fetch the data in our app from both external sources and from our tables and read them together.

UI updates however happen more frequently and if we set some triggers up to execute this `stored_procedure_x` after each insert/update to `table_x` and `table_y`. Then because triggers would get fired off before the commit had gone through instead of after, which would screw with the data.

We're now thinking about the options, one of which was :

- To have the UI(webserver) call this stored procedure in Oracle once they are done inserting or updating data.

I m just brainstorming what to do now, currently I think the above idea is bad, that this might be better solved in the db layer, got any other ideas?

Comment: have you considered creating a mview that can refresh on commit? There will be few conditions to be met for the query but it may solve the issue.